# Python globbing to match find's "-print -quit" behavior

Tags: python, find, glob, subdirectory

I have a few arbitrarily deep directories, each of which contains a single file with a consistent name. In the command line I can use `find <dir> -name <filename> -print -quit` for optimized searching: once it finds the file, it stops looking through the directory. I can do that because it's found exactly what I'm looking for.

I can use glob (or os.walk, I suppose) to do the same thing. But neither of these options seem to have a way to *stop* once the file I'm looking for is found: both index the full directory regardless - globbing looks for as many matches as possible, and os.walk will only allow me to filter after the index is complete.

Is there a way to get that optimized `find` behavior in Python, short of doing a `find` in a subprocess?

Comment: If you use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk():` you can break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't os.walk still index the full structure prior to returning the generator? It doesn't store the full index in memory - hence the generator - but it won't optimize in terms of time.

Comment: I'm not sure. It obviously gets the full contents of each directory sinsce `dirs` and `files` are lists, not generators. But I hope the main loop is generated on the fly rather than enumerating the full hierarchy.

Comment: I think it depends on whether you use `topdown=True` (the default). In topdown mode, changes made during the loop will be visible, which means it didn't index everything up front.

Comment: @Barmar you're absolutely right on that actually. Breaking the os.walk when the file was in `files` timed 15x _faster_ than the `find`. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `topdown=True` option to `os.walk()`, which is the default, it doesn't generate the entire hierarchy first; the generator returns one directory at a time. This allows you to change the `dirlist` value in place to prevent it from descending into some subdirectories, and also allows you to break out of the loop early.